# Modifying body HTML content before DOM is loaded and displayed in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to modify the body of a page before the DOM is displayed using JavaScript or jQuery.

I'm able to do it fairly well with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {          

   jQuery('body').load('?variation-id='+dynamic_id_number, function() {});

});
```

But the problem is that the page renders the old body content for a split second before showing the new body content.

Is there a way I can detect when the DOM is loaded and modify it before it is printed?

Answer (score 4):

If you're waiting for `document.onready`, it'll wait for the dom to be ready ;). Don't use it, just embed it (your script) in your head tag.

Comment: I believe my problem is that even when my code above runs, the page continues to load, and sometimes a bit of the body has already loaded before my code to replace body content can run. Is there a way to prevent the DOM from being displayed until my code tells it to release?

Comment: I still have issue with the old body being loaded and then after a second the new body content loads. 

Something is not right if what you say is true. There should be no display of the original body HTML and only the new HTML loaded through jQuery('body').load() should display, but that is not the case. Chrome seems to show the old content longer than Firefox.

Comment: `.load` is async, so remove the body before

Comment: Is there a way to force .load to be sync? Even if I take the advice of others and hide the body before I still have a moment of blank white page.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM is fully visible at the same instant it is fully loaded.

If you want to avoid this, I suppose you could just hide the body with CSS and show it again when you're done:

CSS:

```
body { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {          
    jQuery('body').load('?variation-id='+dynamic_id_number, function(){
        jQuery('body').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: This does work somewhat but I still experience a small whiteout until the .load() functions works.

Comment: That's the delay while the AJAX request is being performed. If you want to avoid any delay at all, you need to skip AJAX entirely and include your other page server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide `BODY` element contents or `BODY` element itself via CSS:

```css
HTML.hidden > BODY {
    display: none;
}
```

`hidden` class should be added right inside `HEAD` section (while `<body>` opening tag is not even encountered by browser yet):

```js
$(document.documentElement).addClass('hidden');
```

and then unhide it in `ready()` handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.documentElement).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Hiding `BODY` element statically is bad for cases when JS execution is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$(document).ready(..)`, just drop the script directly onto the page, preferably after the element being referenced has been defined. Example:

```
<div id="foo">Bar</div>
<script>$("#foo").html("Loaded!");</script>
```

Its not pretty, but it does the job.

Comment: I do not believe this will work for me because to work with caching plugins for the WordPress CMS I need to use code in .js files to handle the dynamic page loading within the main page. Scripts ran within the html content will be cached and hard to make dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the page's source code, you can try this:

```
var css = 'body { display:none; background-color:white; }',
style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';

if(style.styleSheet)
{
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else
{
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
head.appendChild(style);
```